# ASP Repeater - Not repeating data from xPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath

I have an XML DataSource which feeds a repeater control. However, I'm having some issues getting the actual data to be shown.

The XML DataSource contains a list of Thicknesses of materials (taken from a larger XML file), along with price, size and dimension data:

```
<Thickness>
  <Thick>
    <Size label="Thickness: 12"><![CDATA[12]]></Size>
    <Price>5778</Price>
    <From>0</From>
    <To>0</To>
  </Thick>
  <Thick>
    <Size label="Thickness: 22"><![CDATA[22]]></Size>
    <Price>5919</Price>
    <From>0</From>
    <To>0</To>
  </Thick>
  ...
</Thickness>
```

I load the DataSource with the following code:

```
myThickness.XPath = "/Item[@label='" + tvwMaterials.SelectedNode.Text + "']/Thickness/*";
myThickness.DataBind();
```

(The other XPath stuff is just to get to the Thickness stuff). I then attempt to load it into the repeater (which is databound to the XML DataSource) and display it using the following code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblThickness" runat="server" Text="Thickness: " />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtThickness" runat="server" Text='<%# XPath("Thick/Size") %>' />
        </tr><tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="From: " />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# XPath("Thick/From") %>' />

         /tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This correctly loads the number of controls, but the controls do not show any data. If I change the xPAth in the loading event to:

```
myThickness.XPath = "/Item[@label='" + tvwMaterials.SelectedNode.Text + "']/Thickness";
```

Then the controls do show data, but only for the very first record (12 and 0). I am not familiar enough with xPAth yet to figure out whteher the /* behind Thickness is needed or not, and if it is, how I then would copnstruct the xPAth in the repeater to read out the values. Anyone have any pointers, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load it like this:

```
myThickness.XPath = "/Item[@label='" + tvwMaterials.SelectedNode.Text + "']/Thickness/Thick";
myThickness.DataBind();
```

Your datasource path must refer the repeating element in the xml document.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblThickness" runat="server" Text="Thickness: " />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtThickness" runat="server" Text='<%# XPath("Size") %>' />
        </tr><tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="From: " />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# XPath("From") %>' />

         /tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```